# Creating lines (not just one) from points GPS

Tags: qgis, point, features, route

I have exported GPS points into QGIS. I want a line that shows the route between the points based on the date. I used the points to path tool and it worked. The line shows the route in time. But in the new layer it created there is just one feature, one line. I want a feature/line for each point to point route. Can someone help me out?

[image: I want a line feature per point to point instead of one line from begin to end of the route]

Comment: Did you try the algorithm 'explode' lines?

Comment: I propose to post this as an answer

Comment: Thank you! It works, only the data from the points wasn't included in the data of the lines. I don't know if that is possible at al..

Answer (score 0):

The **Points to Paths** (note the plural **Paths**) plugin should give you exactly what you want!  I've used it numerous times, and it has always performed flawlessly.  If there ever was a competition for the most useful QGIS plugin, it would get my vote!

I've described it in my answers to these previous SE GIS questions:

- [Allocating point attributes as default values for line layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383312/allocating-point-attributes-as-default-values-for-line-layer/383324#383324)
- [Creating line layer from point layer with start and end attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408615/creating-line-layer-from-point-layer-with-start-and-end-attributes/409183#409183)

Comment: Thank you! Too bad it isn't compatible with newer QGIS versions. I have downloaded the older version and tried the tool, but it says: "ValueError: Order field is not an integer type or date format is invalid." The date looks like this: 2021-07-17T07:50:00.000. So as "Date format" I used: %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S. It didn't work. I also tried changing it from string to integer, but it still doesn't work. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The plugin has been updated to make it compatible with the latest 3.X versions of QGIS.  Regarding your error, you're almost there! First, make sure that your datetime data is stored in a *text* field.  Next, note that your data ends with three zeros, indicating thousandths of a second, so your date format should look like **%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f** (note the **.%f**)  Click on the plugin's middle tab (Date Format Reference) for details.  I've never had to use **.%f**, so I can't speak from experience, but it should work.  If it doesn't, and you don't need thousandths, trim it from the data!